# Bootstrap 3.3.1 Modal Backdrop smaller than modal content

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have just upgraded to Bootstrap 3.3.1 from 3.2 due to it being a dependency on the Smart Admin theme that I use. I am using a modal dialog with remote content that is quite long. In the previous version the modal backdrop worked correctly: it was dark and would allow the modal content to scroll to longer than screen whilst remaining dark the entire screen size. e.g. [image: Working Modal]

Now, with version 3.3.1 the size of the modal backdrop is less than the size of the modal content.
[image: backdrop too small]

How can I get it to work correctly?

Here is my code:

```
    <div class="pull-right">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="@Url.Action("Viewprint", new { qGroupId = Model.QuestionGroupId })" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-keyboard="false"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-print"></i>Print Report</a>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="widget-body">            
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
            <div id="modalContainer" class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

If I put the modal outside the widget-body div the same thing happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue has now been resolved in the Bootstrap 3.3.4 release so no hacking code is needed.
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/15881

Comment: Could you please tell mw, where in this aforementioned link , will i find solution.. because i have never used github before.

Comment: You just need to upgrade Bootstrap to be version 3.3.4 or greater. Download from here: http://getbootstrap.com/. And don't forgot to vote this answer up

Answer (score 4):

If the content height of a already-shown modal dialog was increased (eg. click "Add Item" button to expand the "Selected Item List" within the modal-body), you can call this function to recalculate the backdrop:

`$("#YOUR_MODAL_ID").data("bs.modal").handleUpdate();`

It works for me, hope this can help you too!

Answer (score 4):

I also got this problem in bootstrap 3.3.2. Backdrop doesn't resize its background when the modal content change dynamically. This problem also appear from bootstrap 3.3.0+

I fixed it with this:

```
 $('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e){
      $(this).modal('handleUpdate'); //Update backdrop on modal show
      $(this).scrollTop(0); //reset modal to top position
  });
```

Hope this can help!

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely encountering known & not-yet-fixed bugs https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/15418 and/or https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/15136

Answer (score 0):

I used this jQuery hack to get it working:

```
$( window ).on( 'mousemove mouseup', function() {
      $backdrop  = $('.modal-backdrop');
      el_height  = $modal.innerHeight();
    $backdrop.css({
        height: el_height + 20,
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @rhys-stephens answer, I've created a slightly better solution.
The code bellow does not run on every mousemove, instead its fired only when 'shown'/'loaded' event is triggered (works on BS3).

This solution works when the modal is created/shown, some adjustments are required in case you want it to work with dynamic content height..

```
$("#modal, #modal-lg").on('shown.bs.modal, loaded.bs.modal', function () {
  var $modal        = $(this),
      $backdrop     = $('.modal-backdrop'),
      $modalContent = $modal.find('.modal-dialog'),
      $modalHeight  = function() {
        return ($modalContent.height() > $(window).height()) ? $modalContent.height() : $(window).height();
      };

$backdrop.css({
  height: $modalHeight * 1.1
});});
```